# Ubuntu 22.04 Server (ARM64) not connecting to SSH after a power outage from my Win 10 laptop. "Connection Timed Out" error

Tags: linux, networking, server, plex

this is my first post but that’s not important ATM.

I have a Plex Server running on a brand-new Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04 Server LTS.  A storm knocked out power for a second 2 days after installation and setup.  The Pi is powered via a surge protector, so that shouldn't be the issue, but you all have more experience than my 3 days with Linux I assume so correct me if need be.  The machine I am using to SSH into my server is running Win10, and I was using my server prior to the storm hitting today, as well as using SSH to install ease-of-use programs like KeePassXC, these apps are not the issue, I only mention this to express the issue that this has only happened since the power outage.

## Things I have tried:

- Reboot internet router
- Reboot Pi (via HDMI and m&k)
- Reboot Pi (via USB-C power cord)
- Reboot Win10 PC
- Firewall disable (on Pi, have tried to SSH while disabled, still error)
- Firewall enable (on Pi)
- Firewall allow 22 (on Pi) (I have checked status, claims to be running)
- IP reservation turned off and on for both devices
- Some other things I am probably forgetting, been on this for 2 hours now

## Issue:

- When using ssh user@[Pi IP] I get
  `ssh: connect to host [Pi IP] port 22: Connection timed out`
- Same issue when using the hostname
- RDC will not let me see the remote desktop
- Pinging the Pi returns
  `Reply from [Win 10 IP]: Destination host unreachable.` W/ 4 packets sent and received.

## Final comments

I have tried almost every YouTube video/tutorial I can find, but none of them yield results. The goal is to be able to use my Pi headless and access it from my PC to update and manage it, and that worked for a few days, but this storm has ruined my hard work it seems. I'm to the point of just restarting the Pi OS all over as much of a pain as it was to do the first time. Please help with any advice you have, I'm all ears.

Comment: are you sure the pi ip is the same as it was?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is intended primary for programming questions. This is not really a programming question. You might wish to post this on `unix.stackexchange.com` or `serverfault.com` where you'd get more of the type of expertise you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get network access to your pi, thus succeeding in pinging it.

If the ping is not working, you should go on your pi and see if the network configuration is ok, verify that the firewall is disabled, and then try to ping again.

If the configuration seems good to you and the ping isn't working, you should verify that your windows allow outgoing ping, by pinging another machine on your network (next router...)

If the configuration seem's all ok but the ping isn't working, you should. try if the network works well on the pi by trying to ping other machines and try other network accesses.

When the ping is ok, you should be able to ssh to your pi.

If not, you can stop ssh and start it in debug mode /usr/sbin/sshd -D and see what happens when you try to connect.

Comment: So pinging does not work, as I mentioned in my post. It says "Destination Host Unreachable" and returns my laptop IP address.

What do you mean by "check network configuration?"

Pinging some other devices works, like smart tv, but not my phone, returns the same error as above. 

Pinging from the Pi, I tried pinging my laptop which has left it in a blank state on the terminal. I typed in "ping [laptop IP]" and it said "pinging with data" and now it's just sitting there, with no updates, for ~10 minutes.

How do I stop ssh? how do I start it in debug? 

Apologies, I'm very new to this